# Detached persited parent entity when saving unidirectional one-to-one child entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am writing some tests for my first application using spring boot. I created a unidriectional relation between a user and a teacher making use of the @MapsId so that the pks of the user and the teacher are the same. Now i would think that since the relation is only specified on the teacher part, the user will not be saved when invoking a save operation. Though somehow when saving the teacher (new Entity) with a coupled user (persisted in the database) i get a detached entity exception. The relevant part of the entity looks like:

```
@Entity
public class Teacher {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    private User user;

}
```

And the user entity has no reference to the teacher class:

```
@Entity
public class User {
// some fields getters and setters
}
```

In my test i am first creating a user:

```
@Test doSomeUserOperations() {
    User user = new User()
    // set some user info
    userRepository.save(user)

    // next i want to couple a teacher entity via a method in the teacher service
    Teacher teacher = teacherService.getAndCreateTeacherForUser(user.getId());
}
```

With the teacherService looking as follows:

```
@Service
public class TeacherService {
    @Autowired TeacherRepository teacherRepo; (both extending JpaRepo)
    @Autowired UserRepository userRepo;

    public Teacher getAndCreateTeacherForUser(Long userId) {
        Teacher newTeacher = new Teacher();

        newTeacher.setUser(userRepo.findById(userId).get());

        return teacherRepo.save(newTeacher);
    }

}
```

Now on the return line i get the following exception trace:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.dorresteijn.wordteacher.model.User; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.dorresteijn.wordteacher.model.User
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:280)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy154.save(Unknown Source)
at
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is very simple. Your service is not transactional and because of this the read of the User is in different transaction than the persist of the teacher. In between the read and the write it gets detached. Put one @Transactional annotation on top or ensure transactionalbility manualy and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problem of merge logic, I think in this case `save` is used to create new objects and it will complain if the hierarchy is having an already saved `object`. You should use `saveOrUpdate` in such cases, instead of `save`.